# How can I get source code of page thru WebBrowser-Control (ActiveX InternetExplorer)?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control

How can I get source code of page thru WebBrowser Control (ActiveX InternetExplorer)?

I have an xml document "foo.xml".

```
var
 Web: TWebBrowser;
begin
 ...
 Web.Navigate("foo.xml");
 // How can I get source code thru WebBrower control<----
 ...
end;
```

Comment: Isn't it simply the contents of the foo.xml file, which you can load directly anyway?

Comment: I think that might be an example.

Comment: XML is a result of Http request. It's not a file.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this would be easy but it seems it might have been forgotten.  You can easily do it with a TidHTTP control though.

```
MyPage := IdHTTP1.Get('www.google.com');
```

I know its not what you want but might help.

Answer (score 1):

In the DocumentCompleted event, look at the `DocumentText` property of the WebBrowser control. It should have the complete text of the loaded page.

Comment: I see no such property in Delphi 2005. Was it introduced in a later version?

Answer (score 1):

```
IHTMLDocument2(Web.Document).Body.InnerHTML;
```

This should return the source of the page.

Comment: Won't that omit the HEAD element, as well as the opening and closing BODY tags?

Comment: I guess your right.
Maybe this helps you?:
http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=14

Answer (score 1):

Another method which works well is to use [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php).  Use the synapse call HttpGet to retrieve your initial resource (which gives you the source code) then manipulate as needed.

Another option would be to use the [EmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/product.html) component which exposes MANY more properties and features of the web browser than the standard Delphi component does and still fits your requirement of doing it within the web browser.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know how can I do this thru ActiveX only.

Comment: I believe the EmbeddedWB component WRAPS IE, and includes full source.  Its a good starting point to see how its done.

Answer (score 1):

To access the entire HTML of the page through your WebBrowser control use:

```
Web.Document.All[0].OutterHtml;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wbMain.Navigate("foo.xml");
            wbMain.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(testing);
        }

        private void testing(Object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            test = wbMain.DocumentText;
        }
```

I know this is a little late but this works for me.  wbMain is the WebBrowser Object.

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser1.Navigate() loads it into the RAD component window using the built in IE component in the Windows OS. What you do is respond to a callback (for the browser component, double-click the OnDownloadComplete event) and save it to file in that function. Snippets from working code:

```
procedure TMainForm.WB_SaveAs_HTML(WB : TWebBrowser; const FileName : string) ;
var
   PersistStream: IPersistStreamInit;
   Stream: IStream;
   FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
   if not Assigned(WB.Document) then
   begin
     Logg('Document not loaded!') ; //'Logg' adds a line to a log file.
     Exit;
   end;

   PersistStream := WB.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
   FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate) ;
   try
     Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(FileStream, soReference) as IStream;
     if Failed(PersistStream.Save(Stream, True)) then ShowMessage('SaveAs HTML fail!') ;
   finally
     FileStream.Free;
   end;

end; (* WB_SaveAs_HTML *)

procedure TMainForm.WebBrowser1DownloadComplete(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if (WebBrowser1.Document<>nil)AND NOT(WebBrowser1.busy) then begin
       WB_SaveAs_HTML(WebBrowser1,'test.html');
       //myStringList.loadFromFile('test.html');   //process it.
   end;
end;
```

Note that some MIME ("file") types such as JSON give a 'Save As...' dialog in IE, which stops your reading and requires manual intervention.