# mshtml HTMLDocument createDocumentFromUrl in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, web, mshtml

How to use createDocumentFromUrl  in vb.net. I got information like we should use IPersistStreamInit interface if we want to work on this. So i want an example showing this.

Comment: Please inform what solution you chose as a guide to others, preferably as a comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recomend going alone into that interface, But I am guessing that you are doing this in a dll/cmd line so you can't use the winform solution so you can use htmlAgility pack and you can download it as a nuget [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

But If you have to go the interop way you can check out this question [Getting the HTML source from a WPF-WebBrowser-Control using IPersistStreamInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516747/getting-the-html-source-from-a-wpf-webbrowser-control-using-ipersiststreaminit)

And the only thing you need to add for vb is this

```
  Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
     Dispose()
     GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
  End Sub
```

But using the agility pack you can do it like this:

```
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.IO
    Imports HtmlAgilityPack


    Class Program
        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim wc As New WebClient()
            Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
            doc.Load(wc.OpenRead("http://google.com"))
        End Sub
    End Class
```